# Is there a traditional card game with similar rules to "Lost Cities"?

Tags: history, lost-cities

It's often pointed out that the excellent Reiner Knizia card game, [Lost Cities](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/50/lost-cities), could [be played with a standard deck of cards if there were one extra suit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lost_Cities#Summary).  Thinking about the simplicity and elegance of the rules made me wonder if there might exist a traditional card game with similar mechanics but just four suits/cities?  (I don't know many traditional card games, so I'm not even sure if there's a broad category that Lost Cities might fall into.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think I've ever heard of such card game. To me it's pretty clear that Lost Cities were developed and designed using standard card deck, but I don't suspect it's actually based on some truly similar traditional card game. Maybe the basic idea was to design a 2-player game with simple rules, something a little like Solitaire, but competetive, with  piles shared between the players?

I heard Lost Cities being described as *2 player Solitaire with an extra portion of suspense* - [source](http://toucharcade.com/2012/08/14/reiner-knizias-lost-cities-coming-to-the-app-store-courtesy-of-carcassonne-developer-thecodemonkeys/). If there was more similar game to Lost Cities, maybe such descriptions would mention it.

I guess this isn't the answer you were looking for, although I can't give you any game title that would have the feel of Lost Cities. [This](http://www.convivium.org.uk/kgfgi.htm) is the interview with Reiner Knizia in which he mentions origins of Lost Cities. You also may want to take a look at [this interview](http://www.convivium.org.uk/kgbgn3.htm) and [this one](http://candidlook.blogspot.com/2009/03/censored-interview-with-reiner-knizia.html).

> It started out as a two-player card game. I then tried to develop it into a larger game that would accommodate between two and four players. In the end, I came to the conclusion that I wanted to leave it as I originally had it [as a two player game]. When I start out with a game, it is usually unclear where I will end up with it. If you build up internal obstacles and say "this has to be a card game" or "this has to be a tile-laying game" then you restrict yourself. I think you need to do the game justice -- you need to let it develop. Lost Cities developed into a two-player game: it is clean, it is pure, it is simple, it is challenging, and it is fun.

You might also try checking [Patience category](http://www.pagat.com/patience/) on pagat.com